# How to run appium iphone test scripts in sequential in one Mac machin in two device

Tags: appium

I ma trying to run test appium iPhone test scripts sequential in two devices like for chat scenario, But I am getting issue that one session started another not started.

Also, I tried with two appium server in different-2 port and created two set of appium object in script but noticed that application launched in two devices but execute in one device.

Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue and run appium server instance with different port and bootstrap-port. then test run sequential in two different-2 divices